# Сократить код в jquery

Tags: jquery

Помогите сократить код:

```
$('#go-to-section-1').on('click', function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#section-1').offset().top - 100
    }, 300);
});

$('#go-to-section-2').on('click', function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#section-2').offset().top - 100
    }, 300);
});

$('#go-to-section-3').on('click', function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#section-3').offset().top - 100
    }, 300);
});
```

Хочу вот эту часть перенести в переменную, но не знаю как:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#section-3').offset().top - 100
}, 300);
```

Чтобы выводилось на подобии как:

```
$('#go-to-section-1').on('click', function() {
    myTarget('#section-1'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id^='go-to-section-']").on('click', function() {

  function myTarget(index) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#section-' + index).offset().top - 100
    }, 300);
  };

  var parts = this.id.split("-");
  myTarget(parts[parts.legth - 1]); 
});
```

Comment: Хорошо бы еще добавить объяснение того что вы сделали